# Why are statements with no effect considered legal in C?

Tags: c

Pardon if this question is naive. Consider the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int i = 1;
  i = i + 2;
  5;
  i;
  printf("i: %d\n", i);
}
```

In the above example, the statements `5;` and `i;` seem totally superfluous, yet the code compiles without warnings or errors by default (however, gcc does throw a `warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]` warning when ran with `-Wall`). They have no effect on the rest of the program, so why are they considered valid statements in the first place? Does the compiler simply ignore them? Are there any benefits to allowing such statements?

Comment: What are the benefits of banning such statements?

Comment: Also, what happens when you turn the warning level up?

Comment: Any expression can be a statement by putting `;` after it. It would complicate the language to add more rules about when expressions can't be statements

Comment: @MooingDuck that's precisely the sort of insight I hope to glean from this question. I also didn't know about extra warning levels, I'll edit the question accordingly

Comment: Would you rather have your code fail to compile because you ignore the return value of `printf()`?  The statement `5;` basically says "do whatever `5` does (nothing) and ignore the result.  Your statement `printf(...)` is "do whatever `printf(...)` does **and ignore the results** (the return value from `printf()`)".  C treats those the same.  This also allows for code such as `(void) i;` where `i` is a parameter to a function that you cast to `void` to mark it as deliberately unused.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: That's not quite the same, because calling `printf()` does have an effect, even if you ignore the value it eventually returns.  By contrast `5;` has no effect at all.

Comment: Because Dennis Ritchie, and he is not around to tell us.

Comment: @NateEldredge True. They're not the same. But even then the side effects of an expression (such as the results of calling `printf()`) are separated from where the results of that expression wind up.  You can call a function and ignore the return code just like you can ignore the value of something like `5;`.  C is consistent about that.  Trying to make code like `5;` some type of syntax error would likely complicate the heck out of the language grammar.  (Compiler theory was way too many decades ago...)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One benefit to allowing such statements is from code that's created by macros or other programs, rather than being written by humans.

As an example, imagine a function  `int do_stuff(void)` that is supposed to return 0 on success or -1 on failure.  It could be that support for "stuff" is optional, and so you could have a header file that does

```
#if STUFF_SUPPORTED
#define do_stuff() really_do_stuff()
#else
#define do_stuff() (-1)
#endif
```

Now imagine some code that wants to do stuff if possible, but may or may not really care whether it succeeds or fails:

```
void func1(void) {
    if (do_stuff() == -1) {
        printf("stuff did not work\n");
    }
}

void func2(void) {
    do_stuff(); // don't care if it works or not
    more_stuff();
}
```

When `STUFF_SUPPORTED` is 0, the preprocessor will expand the call in `func2` to a statement that just reads

```
    (-1);
```

and so the compiler pass will see just the sort of "superfluous" statement that seems to bother you.  Yet what else can one do?  If you `#define do_stuff() // nothing`, then the code in `func1` will break.  (And you'll still have an empty statement in `func2` that just reads `;`, which is perhaps even more superfluous.)  On the other hand, if you have to actually define a `do_stuff()` function that returns -1, you may incur the cost of a function call for no good reason.

Comment: A more classic version (or do I mean common version) of the no-op is `((void)0)`.

Comment: A good example of this is [`assert`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/assert.html).

Answer (score 3):

Simple Statements in C are terminated by semicolon.

Simple Statements in C are expressions. An expression is a combination of variables, constants and operators. Every expression results in some value of a certain type that can be assigned to a variable.

Having said that some "smart compilers" might discard 5; and i; statements.

Comment: I can't imagine any compiler that would do anything with those statements other than discard them.  What else could it do with them?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: A very simple, non-optimizing compiler might very well generate code to compute the value and put the result in a register (from which point it would be ignored).

Comment: The C standard doesn't the term "simple statement". An *expression statement* consists of an (optional) expression followed by a semicolon. Not every expression results in a value; an expression of type `void` has no value.

Answer (score 2):

Statements with no effect are permitted because it would be more difficult to ban them than to permit them. This was more relevant when C was first designed and compilers were smaller and simpler.

An *expression statement* consists of an expression followed by a semicolon. Its behavior is to evaluate the expression and discard the result (if any). Normally the purpose is that the evaluation of the expression has side effects, but it's not always easy or even possible to determine whether a given expression has side effects.

For example, a function call is an expression, so a function call followed by a semicolon is a statement. Does this statement have any side effects?

```
some_function();
```

It's impossible to tell without seeing the implementation of `some_function`.

How about this?

```
obj;
```

Probably not -- but if `obj` is defined as `volatile`, then it does.

Permitting *any* expression to be made into an *expression-statement* by adding a semicolon makes the language definition simpler. Requiring the expression to have side effects would add complexity to the language definition and to the compiler. C is built on a consistent set of rules (function calls are expressions, assignments are expressions, an expression followed by a semicolon is a statement) and lets programmers do what they want without preventing them from doing things that may or may not make sense.

Answer (score 2):

The statements you listed with no effect are examples of an **expression statement**, whose syntax is given in section 6.8.3p1 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) as follows:

```
 expression-statement:
   expressionopt ;
```

All of section 6.5 is dedicated to the definition of an expression, but loosely speaking an **expression** consists of constants and identifiers linked with operators.  Notably, an expression may or may not contain an assignment operator and it may or may not contain a function call.

So *any* expression followed by a semicolon qualifies as an expression statement.  In fact, each of these lines from your code is an example of an expression statement:

```
i = i + 2;
5;
i;
printf("i: %d\n", i);
```

Some operators contain side effects such as the set of assignment operators and the pre/post increment/decrement operators, and the function call operator `()` *may* have a side effect depending on what the function in question does.  There is no requirement however that one of the operators must have a side effect.

Here's another example:

```
atoi("1");
```

This is calling a function and discarding the result, just like the call `printf` in your example but the unlike `printf` the function call itself does not have a side effect.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes such a statements are very handy:

```
int foo(int x, int y, int z)
{
    (void)y;   //prevents warning
    (void)z;

    return x*x;
}
```

Or when reference manual tells us to just read the registers to archive something - for example to clear or set some flag (very common situation in the uC world)

```
#define SREG   ((volatile uint32_t *)0x4000000)
#define DREG   ((volatile uint32_t *)0x4004000)

void readSREG(void)
{
    *SREG;   //we read it here
    *DREG;   // and here
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/6wjh_5

Comment: When `*SREG` is volatile, `*SREG;` does not have no effect in the model specified by the C standard. The C standard specifies it has an observable side effect.

Comment: @EricPostpischil - no it does not have the **observable** effect, but if has the effect.  None of the C visible objects have changed.

Comment: C 2018 5.1.2.3 6 defines the *observable behavior* of the program to include that “Accesses to volatile objects are evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine.” There is no question of interpretation or deduction; this is the **definition** of observable behavior.