# What does data on a line by itself do in C? It doesn't seem to be compiled in the binary

Tags: c

What does this code do?

```
void main(void)
{
 "Hello World!"; //This, which doesn't seem to be included in the binary
 0; //And other stuff
}
```

It seems like valid C code but I'm unsure as to what it is for.

Comment: The compiler is free to remove any unused expressions.  You need to assign that string to something: `char *greeting = "Hello World!";`, but if nothing references `greeting`, the compiler or the linker are free to remove it as well.

Comment: Just because something is a valid sentence in a language doesn't mean it's also a useful sentence or one that's at all sensible. Any optimizing compiler will eliminate such unused side-effect-free expression statements.

Comment: If you want to prin5 stuff to console you could use printf()

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60443430/827263 . Also, `void main(void)` should be `int main(void)`. If you have a book that told you to use `void main(void)`, get rid of it and find a better one.

Comment: These are little more than comments.  The only use I know of for things like this is to create a reference to an otherwise unreferenced variable (to avoid compiler warnings).

Comment: @TomKarzes That's right. To make it obvious, its common practice to write `(void)unreferenced;`

Comment: @thebusybee Yes, I always include the void cast when I do that.